# Difference between "SOAPAction:" and "SOAPAction" HTTP request property

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I was checking how to perform SOAP calls without using any library like jax-ws, just using a normal HttpURLConnection. When reading documentation I found in some places

> conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction);

And in other places

> conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction:", soapAction);

But I couldn't find the difference between these two headers. Well, I found one, when using "SOAPAction:", if the action was misspelled, the ":" was like part of the name of the action.

Does someone know the difference? Or is "SOAPAction:" simply wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SOAPAction:` is wrong. HTTP adds the colon. A colon isn't allowed in a header name, in fact.

Comment: Then does Java have some kind of correction? Because I had other headers like "conn.setRequestProperty("Connection:", "Keep-Alive");" and everything was running just fine.

Comment: It was probably ignoring that header - it's not essential. Also, why on earth are you using `HttpURLConnection` for SOAP? There are dozens of libraries for it.

Comment: I needed to create the SOAP call without any library. Anyway, thanks for the help!